# Global constant declared but cannot be used in given function for declaring array length

Tags: c++, arrays, global

See line 91 of code,

array<double,size1> poundData; //PROBLEM HERE array declared

Global constant size1 can be used to represent integer value 5 everywhere else in code but returns an error if used for declaring the array length.

If size1 is replaced with 5 on this line, code runs perfectly, but need size1 to be used for flexibility. Cannot see why it won't allow size1 to be used, but am very much a beginner so may be something very basic i'm missing.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<time.h>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

const int size1 = 5; // declare global constant

double randValInRange (double min,double max,int size1,int i); //Declare functions

array<double,size1> fillArray(double min,double max,int size1);


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  
  
  if (argc >= 3)   //Determine if there are at least 3 command line arguments
    {
      double min;
      double max;
      double input1;
      double input2;
      input1 = atof (argv[1]);
      input2 = atof (argv[2]);

      if (input1 <= 0.0||input2 <= 0.0) {     // Determine that both inputs are positive
      cout << " \n min and max must both be positive values\n";

      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
       
      if (input1 < input2){
      min = input1;
      max = input2;
    }else{

      min = input2;
      max = input1;
    }

      cout << min << " lbs is min \n";
      cout << max << " lbs is max \n\n";

      srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));

      // std::
    array<double,size1> poundData;

      poundData =  fillArray(min,max,size1);
   

      
   
      for (int i=0;i<size1;i++) {
    cout<<poundData[i]<<"   ";

    cout<<"\n";
        }

} else {

  cout << "Incorrect number of arguments - please call as follows: " <<argv[0] << " min max\n";
    }
  return 0;
}

double randValInRange (double min,double max,int size1,int i ){
    
  double scale = 100000.0;
  double range = max - min;
    
  double rangeScaled = range*scale;
  int rangeScaledInt = (static_cast<int>(rangeScaled));
    
  double minScaled = min * scale;
  int minScaledInt = (static_cast<int>(minScaled));
    
  int randIntScaled = rand()%(rangeScaledInt);
  int outputValueScaled = minScaledInt + randIntScaled;
  double outputValueScaledD = static_cast<double>(outputValueScaled);
  double outputValue = outputValueScaledD/scale;

  return outputValue;
}

array<double,size1> fillArray (double min,double max,int size1) //function with return type array
{
 
  array<double,size1> poundData; //**PROBLEM HERE** array declared
    
  
  for (int i=0;i<size1;i++) {

    double outputValue = randValInRange (min,max,size1,i);
    poundData[i] = outputValue;
     
        }
  return poundData;

}
```

Comment: You can use `::` scope operator like `array<double,::size1>` to avoid this problem. This is explained in any [beginner c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) which are also available as PDFs for free.

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
const int size1 = 5; // declare global constant
```

`size1` is a constant expression. For clarity you could have used `constexpr`:

```
constexpr int size1 = 5;
```

Here:

```
double randValInRange (double min,double max,int size1,int i ){
```

The parameter called `size1` shadows the global variable of same name. Inside the function `size1` refers to the argument which is **not** a constant expression.

Use more meaningful names than `size1`, then such name clashes are less likely.

And better avoid global variables. For example rather than defining the size globally you could have declared a type alias globally:

```
using array_type = std::array<double,5>;
```

Well, actually this isnt really much better than the `int` when declared globally, but for now it would avoid your current issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
array<double,size1> fillArray (double min,double max,int size1/*!!!*/)
{                           
// here size1 is a parameter and this hide the global constant size1
}
```